# how to list the paired bluetooth devices from iphone corebluetooth api

Tags: iphone, core-bluetooth

I am trying to list the paired bluetooth devices.
I know that I can get the list of connected devices by using retrieveConnectedPeripherals.

So my question is how I can get paired devices programatically from iphone SDK.

Thanking you all in advance.

Regards

Bhaban

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of available Bluetooth devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178293/how-to-get-list-of-available-bluetooth-devices)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [BluetoothSerial](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial). it will serve you all what you want.

**Lists bonded devices**

```
bluetoothSerial.list(success, failure);
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but a problem with the project is that it needs PhoneGap. Installing PhoneGap _and_ this plugin is pretty heavy for solving this task.