# How to get nearby Bluetooth Devices in IOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want to get nearby devices whose bluetooth is on without making any connection. I searched a lot for this but did'nt find any solution. The solutions I found, list nearby devices only when advertised from both sides or by making session from both sides. I do not want to connect with devices, but just want to get the the devices which are in range and their bluetooth is on. Is their any way to do this?

Hope, I explained my question well.

If there is any ambiguity, you can ask me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of available Bluetooth devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178293/how-to-get-list-of-available-bluetooth-devices)

Comment: The link you mentioned, may be the duplicate. But I don't think so. His question is about core bluetooth and CBUUID. Probably he wanted to make communication between devices. But I don't want any connection. I just want to get the devices whose bluetooth is on without pairing them . And according to my knowledge(may be wrong), core bluetooth cannot do this.