# Listing My Bluetooth Devices iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, sdk

I would like to know if there is a way to write an app to identify the Bluetooth devices under My Devices on my iPhone. Additionally, I would like to list which devices are currently connected or not.

I have worked a bit with a developer and he claims it is not available in any SDK. I find this difficult to believe.

I know I can scan for all Bluetooth devices near me and I have developed an app to do that but I still want to also list the apps on my phone and their connection status.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: not getting question properly!!! What you want exactly ? list of device in your range with Bluetooth enable?

Comment: I would like to list the BlueTooth devices on my phone under "My Devices" and be able to select one to monitor its connection status.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
  NSArray *connectedAccessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];
```

For scan you can do,

```
CBUUID *heartRate = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"];


NSDictionary *scanOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];


[cm scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:heartRate] options:scanOptions]
```

You can refer [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178293/how-to-get-list-of-available-bluetooth-devices) or [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636637/possible-to-generate-a-list-of-connected-bluetooth-devices-for-ios).

Comment: Thanks Ketan. I will see if this helps my developer.