# iOS bluetooth paired device list

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need paired Bluetooth device information on iOS.
How do I find a paried device on my iPhone?

When the paired device is reconnected by inputting the pin number, it is connected without inputting the pin number.
Is there any way to connect by entering the pin number?

Comment: I think this link helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178293/how-to-get-list-of-available-bluetooth-devices

Comment: There is no API to retrieve paired peripherals. You can save the peripheral identifier and use `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` to try and get a reference to it later.  Once a peripheral is bonded, the user will not be prompted for a PIN unless the bonding is broken by removing the peripheral from settings

Comment: Is there a way to remove bonding with code?

Comment: @leptir have you found a way to retrieve the devices list?